# Quick way to set background to transparant

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png, adobe-photoshop-elements

What is the quickest way to set a transparant background to jpg image with a white background without any major editing?

I have tried a few online solutions but the quality always seems poor, so any online resources would be useful too.

Comment: it depends on the image. if they are complex enough, you should remove background manually.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick, easy way that I've found to remove a white background:

1) Use the Quick Selection Tool (<kbd>w</kbd>) and paint around the inside of the object that you wish to isolate from its background.  You might need to go in and manually deselect some areas, by holding down <kbd>ALT</kbd> while you paint.

2) Click on Refine Edge at the top of your screen and adjust your settings, to achieve a desired selection edge.  These are the settings that I used, but yours will likely be different:

**Update:** in newer versions of PS, this has been restructured into "Select and mask..."

[image]

3) Once you're happy with how the selection looks, click on Add a Layer Mask at the bottom of your Layers Palette:

[image]

You've now converted your white background to transparent, while also maintaining the ability to reverse and/or edit any of your steps in the previous steps through editing the mask you've created.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use actions like this one http://mediamilitia.com/removing-a-white-background-with-photoshop-actions/ 
But the quality is always linked to the quality of the jpg and the amount of artefacts.